# Jmeter Performance Test - Perfmon and Server Agent

Tags: jmeter

How accurate are the results of Perfmon (Server health Performance) when compared to Windows Performance Monitor. Are they reliable?

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are

[image: PerfMon vs TaskMgr]

Moreover, you can configure Windows Performance Monitor to store "interesting" counters in CSV format and use JMeter PerfMon [TAIL](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonMetrics/#TAIL) command to read and plot the values

[image: PerfMon CSV]

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
for more information on using JMeter PerfMon plugin

Answer (score 0):

They are exactly the same and comparable with each other. Type perfmon from the run command, it will open Windows Performance Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The jmeter agent that collect metrics is right. But I want to say that the network IO that jmeter agent collect includes loopback IO, whose result is same as `ifstat -l` shows rather than  `ifstat`.